# vaadin component setstylename has no effect

Tags: css, vaadin, vaadin7

The following should work. But it does not. (Css change has no effect whatsoever) What went wrong?

```
@Theme("mytheme")
@Widgetset("de.datalovers.MyAppWidgetset")
public class MyUI extends UI {

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest vaadinRequest) {
        verticalLayout = new VerticalLayout();
        String s = "Montag 07:30 - 12:00"
        Label label = new Label();
        label.setStyleName("mystyle");
```

mytheme.sccs:

```
    @import "../valo/valo.scss";

@mixin mytheme {
  @include valo;

  // Insert your own theme rules here

  .mystyle{

    color: blue;
    background: yellow;
    font-size: 40px;

  }
}
```

styles.sccs

```
@import "mytheme.scss";
@import "addons.scss";

// This file prefixes all rules with the theme name to avoid causing conflicts with other themes.
// The actual styles should be defined in mytheme.scss

.mytheme {
  @include addons;
  @include mytheme;
}
```

Comment: Should work that way... Have you looked in the DOM if the class `mystyle` is assigned to the Label element? If yes, then look at the style rules, perhaps there is something else "more importatant" overwriting your settings. (I assume you have compiled the theme...?)

Comment: You need to recompile the theme OR run Vaadin in development mode. With development mode be careful, that vaadin may cache a dynamically compiled stylesheet forever if the scss is coming from the classpath instead of the web folder of a web project due to a bug. Always check that the stylesheet itself is recompiled whenever you change it when in doubt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont forget to empty cache (CTRL + F5) when working with CSS and Vaadin. And recompile theme after working on your stylesheets.